# Prove that $d$ is a metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

It is given that $d$ is a real-valued function on $X \times X$ which for all x, y and z in X satisfies $d(x,y)=0$ iff x=y and $$d(x,y)+d(x,z)\geq d(y,z)$$

In order to show that $d$ is a metric is left for me to show that $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$.
I guess I cannot wrap my head around it at the time. I am working on it now.
Thank you for your help!
Now $$d(y,x)\leq d(z,y)+d(z,x)$$

Comment: Is the property $d(x,y)+d(x,z)\geq d(y,z)$ or $d(x,y)+d(y,z)\geq d(x,z)$?

Comment: Don't you also need to show that $d(x,y) \ge 0$?  I don't see it specified anywhere.

Comment: @ Erick you probably right, I think i need to show that as well, I dont know why I keep thinking thats irrelevant, but it not.. you are right

Comment: @Asaf I wrote it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\underline{d(x,y)}=d(x,y) + d(x,x)+d(y,y)\underline{\geq d(y,x)}+d(y,y)\underline{\geq d(x,y)}.$$

For non-negativity a similar argument applies:
$$2d(x,y)=d(x,y)+d(x,y)\geq d(y,y)=0\implies d(x,y)\geq 0.$$

Comment: Do you have any ideas about showing non-negativity of $d$?

Comment: @Amr: Yes.${}{}$

Comment: Ah. I see. ${}{}$ (+1)

Comment: @ Asaph, so you show that d(x,y)>=d(x,y)? what does this prove?

Comment: @Klara: No, I show that $d(x,y)\geq d(y,x)\geq d(x,y)$. Also, it's **Asaf**.

Comment: @Asaph oh I see, nicely done!

Answer (score 1):

$d(x,y)=d(x,y)+d(x,x) \geq d(y,x) $  and $d(y,x)=d(y,x)+d(y,y)\geq d(x,y)$

So $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$

Comment: Do you have any ideas about showing non-negativity of d?